# Ansible Windows win_command answer by yes or no to prompt

Tags: windows, ansible, command

Could you please help on how can I answer by yes or no using Ansible to a bat executed on a windows host ?

```
 - name: Run upgrade bat
  win_command: "{{ upgrade_bat_name }}"
    args:
      chdir: '{{ item.backup_dir_path }}\dbscript\oracle\windows_cmd\update'
  with_items: "{{ sites_info }}"
  register: upgrade_bat_output
- fail:
    msg: "Errors detected while running upgrade bat"
  when: item != ""
  with_items: "{{ upgrade_bat_output | json_query('results[*].stderr') | list }}"
```

Thanks